# How to split string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have some string patterns. Each pattern consist of two characters "A" and "B".
My patterns are like "AA" or "ABA" or "AABBABA" or ...

I want to split these patterns and the output for these examples must be like: {"AA"} or {"A","B","A"} or {"AA","BB","A","B","A"}

What I tried so far :

```
String pattern = "AABBABA" //or whatever   
String firstChar = pattern.toString().substring(1, 2);
String[] split = pattern.split(firstChar);
for (String string : split) {
    Log.i("findPattern", "Splitted Pattern: " + string + "");
}
```

The problem with my code is that it removes all strings that are equal to `firstChar`.

What regular expression should I use to split my patterns to separated strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind this is, `(.)\\1+` helps to match any number of repeated characters at very first and this `|.` helps to match all the other single characters. Finally put all the matched characters into a list and then print it.

```
   String s = "AABBABA";
   ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();


        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+|.");
        Matcher m = regex.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()){

           fields.add(m.group(0));

    }
    System.out.println(fields);
}
```

Output:

```
[AA, BB, A, B, A]
```

By defining all the above input inside an array.

```
   String s[] = {"AA", "ABA", "AABBABA"};
   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+|.");
   for(String i:s)
   {
       ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = regex.matcher(i);
        while(m.find()){

           fields.add(m.group(0));


    }
        System.out.println(fields);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[AA]
[A, B, A]
[AA, BB, A, B, A]
```

Comment: thanks so much that's what exactly I want

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your logics and got this code, perhaps, not what you want:

```
String pattern = "AABBABA"; //or whatever   
String firstChar = pattern.toString().substring(1, 2);
String[] split = pattern.split("(?!" + firstChar + ")");
for (String strng : split) 
{
   System.console().writer().println(strng);
}
```

Output:

```
AA                                                                                                                                  
B                                                                                                                                   
BA                                                                                                                                  
BA
```

Or try the `Matcher`:

```
// String to be scanned to find the pattern.
String line = "AABBABA";
String pattern1 = "(A+|B+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
int count = 0;
while(m.find()) 
{
   count++;
   System.console().writer().println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
AA                                                                                                                                                                  
BB                                                                                                                                                                  
A                                                                                                                                                                   
B                                                                                                                                                                   
A
```

Comment: good but my expected output must be like : "AA","BB","A","B","A"

Comment: @Milad: See updated answer. Took me long :(

Comment: thanks so much im testing that right now ;)

Comment: yes your answer works for me too, sorry that i cant accept this as an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you may capture what you want instead of split using this pattern

```
(A+|B+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/238)

Comment: yes, that's what I want and how can I implement it in java?